# How to download Planet 3-month mosaics using the API

Tags: planet

I would like to download Planet 3-month mosiacs using the RestFUL API, but I'm not sure what to specify for the `item_type`. The documentation here https://developers.planet.com/docs/api/items-assets/#assets lists a bunch of item types but they seem to be individual tiles.

Is it possible to use Planet's API to download 3 month mosaics, and if so, how?

Comment: By the way, I see a very similar question posted here with no response: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300156/download-3-month-composite-images-from-planet-com, Planet suggests that user support be posted on this stackexchange with the tag [planet] which is why I'm posting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI for anyone else who might run across this in the future. I directly contacted someone at Planet and they reported what I was experiencing was a bug. They also promptly fixed it and the following query format now works:

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: api-key [redacted]" https://api.planet.com/basemaps/v1/mosaics
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download basemaps, you can use the Basemaps API: https://developers.planet.com/docs/api/reference/#tag/Basemaps-and-Mosaics

Comment: So I did that, like this: `curl -L -H "Authorization: api-key [redacted]" https://api.planet.com/basemaps/v1/mosaics` and I get back an empty list of mosaics. Does this mean my API key does not have access to Planet mosacis?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This is a "contact sales" moment, but there's also a limited trial: https://www.planet.com/basemaps-trial/

Comment: Thanks @patrick-armstrong, I did contact sales and they reported what I was experiencing was a bug which they promptly fixed.